# 'require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError) error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, rails-migrations

When I run rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Add `rake` to your `Gemfile` and re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: is it single error string?

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:migrate` ??

Comment: I already have rake in my gemfile yet it still throws the error. What is a single error string? (sorry I'm a newbie)

Comment: bundle exec rake db:migrate doesn't work

Comment: are you actually in the rails project?

Comment: Yes I am in the rails project